# Gross receipts tax liability when operating an LLC in New Mexico as a nonresident alien

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, limited-liability-company, new-mexico

The title pretty much sums it up: will I be exempt from gross receipts tax if I'll be operating my New Mexico single-member LLC from abroad, as a nonresident alien, offering remote services (software development)?

Comment: Why do you expect your location to change the tax liability of the LLC?  Other NM businesses owned by outsiders pay NM GRT, don’t they?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Please take a look at the following sources:
https://ustax.bz/non-us-entrepreneurs/
https://www.myusacorporation.com/articles/taxation-of-foreign-entrepreneurs#bm30

They refer to federal tax liability, but I assume the same rules would apply to GRT. What I'm asking about is whether this is assumption is true or not.

Comment: GRT is a state tax, not a federal tax.  Although you are not in NM, you've set the LLC up in NM, so the LLC may owe GRT to New Mexico.  It does seem clear that if your LLC wasn't based in NM, you wouldn't owe GRT.